# I cannot get a smooth jump

Tags: c++, sdl, game-physics

This is my code for handling movement:

```
void Movement(const Uint8 *keyboardHandle)
{
    if (keyboardHandle[SDL_SCANCODE_SPACE] && yes == 0)
    {
        velY = -20;
        yes = 100;
    }

    player.posY += velY;
    player.posY += g;
    
    if (player.posY >= SCREEN_HEIGHT - player.width / 2)
    {
        player.posY = SCREEN_HEIGHT - player.width / 2;
    }

    velY = 0;

    // Timer
    yes--;
    if(yes <= 0)
    {
        yes = 0;
    }
}
```

It is basic, but all works besides the jump, it just teleport the player upwards.
I tried handling the gravity before the jump, not working. I tried making a `for` loop to increment the Y velocity, still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Dear @yesyes, Stackoverflow is not a platform for debugging your simple homework/assignments. If you put in a little thought then you will be able to solve your problem (as well as get better in the profession). A questions like this (and it's solution) will not give any other user any value. Please ask questions which are less personal for a specific line of code and more general which will add value to other users.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved it.

```
void Movement(const Uint8 *keyboardHandle)
{
    if (keyboardHandle[SDL_SCANCODE_SPACE] && yes == 0)
    {
        g = -10;
        yes = 50;
    }

    player.posX += velX;
    player.posY += g;
    
    if (player.posY >= SCREEN_HEIGHT - player.width / 2)
    {
        player.posY = SCREEN_HEIGHT - player.width / 2;
    }

    // Jump force
    g++;
    if(g >= 5)
    {
        g = 5;
    }

    // Jump timer
    yes--;
    if(yes <= 0)
    {
        yes = 0;
    }
}
```

`g` is by default `5` which would be the gravity, and we just smoothly invert it for a jump.